# Json Convert to string of array

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "response_code": "AVAILABLE",
    "remittance": {
        "transaction_id": "c2e7de4a-7646-4ff4-986c-e5a0c87c48d8",
        "status": "NEW",
        "source_reference_number": "RN-0006",
        "remitter": {
            "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
            "first_name": null,
            "middle_name": null,
            "last_name": null,
            "contact_number": null,
            "account_number": null,
            "address": {
                "address_1": "Manila",
                "country": "PH"
            },
            "identification": {
                "name": "SSS",
                "number": "2313",
                "type": "SSS_ID",
                "expiry_date": "2018-01-01",
                "place_of_issue": "Manila"
            }
        },
        "beneficiary": {
            "name": "Jane Dela Cruz",
            "first_name": null,
            "middle_name": null,
            "last_name": null,
            "contact_number": null,
            "account_number": null,
            "address": {
                "address_1": "Manila",
                "country": "PH"
            },
            "identification": {
                "name": "",
                "number": "",
                "type": "",
                "expiry_date": null,
                "place_of_issue": ""
            }
        },
        "payout_amount": {
            "currency": "PHP",
            "amount": "5000.00"
        },
        "remarks": null,
        "value_date": "2016-03-21",
        "date_created": "2016-03-21 07:24:44 UTC"
    },
    "response_message": "Transaction Available For Payout."
}
```

I got this response in json using winform i want to convert this as an array.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: There are quite a few questions about Json. Did you look to see if any of those helped?

Comment: Why would you want to store this as an array?  Surely it needs to be represented as a map ...

Comment: I want to split them... I'm reading about Jsonconvert.Deserializeobject but i have no idea yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On site [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) generete classes from your JSON. And deserialize your JSON into generated classes. Sometimes tool generates not ideal classes, so be carefull.

```
public class Address
{
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Identification
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string expiry_date { get; set; }
    public string place_of_issue { get; set; }
}

public class Remitter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object first_name { get; set; }
    public object middle_name { get; set; }
    public object last_name { get; set; }
    public object contact_number { get; set; }
    public object account_number { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public Identification identification { get; set; }
}

public class Beneficiary
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object first_name { get; set; }
    public object middle_name { get; set; }
    public object last_name { get; set; }
    public object contact_number { get; set; }
    public object account_number { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public Identification identification { get; set; }
}

public class PayoutAmount
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}

public class Remittance
{
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string source_reference_number { get; set; }
    public Remitter remitter { get; set; }
    public Beneficiary beneficiary { get; set; }
    public PayoutAmount payout_amount { get; set; }
    public object remarks { get; set; }
    public string value_date { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string response_code { get; set; }
    public Remittance remittance { get; set; }
    public string response_message { get; set; }
}
```

And using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) deserialize object into classes:

```
string json = "...Your json..."
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```